# Dose android apps run slower on android-14 when select a low sdk version code during build?

Tags: android, android-layout, compiler-optimization, target-sdk, android-14

I created two simple demo prj in Android Studio. I set one target SDK to 34 and the other one to 30. They executed the same code just to inflate a simple layout. But I found that the app in SDK 34 runs much faster(only took 1/10 inflating time) than the app build in SDK 30.
Dose it mean all app shouldn't compatible for the old SDK in order to execute more effeciency?

Anybody noticed this phenomenon? And did google give any offically explaination?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.